# How to use webpack custom config with react js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I'm using a custom webpack config file which is :

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');
module.exports = {
    entry: {
        app: './src/index.js'
    },
    output: {
        filename: 'dist/bundle.js',
        sourceMapFilename: 'dist/bundle.map'
    },
    devtool: '#source-map',
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                exclude: /(node_modules)/,
                query: {
                    presets: [ 'react', 'es2015' ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

It throws an error when  I run`wepback` in terminal :

```
Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
 - configuration.module has an unknown property 'loaders'. These properties are valid:
   object { defaultRules?, exprContextCritical?, exprContextRecursive?, exprContextRegExp?, exprContextRequest?, noParse?, rules?, strictExportPresence?, strictThisContextOnImports?, unknownContextCritical?, unknownContextRecursive?, unknownContextRegExp?, unknownContextRequest?, unsafeCache?, wrappedContextCritical?, wrappedContextRecursive?, wrappedContextRegExp? }
   -> Options affecting the normal modules (`NormalModuleFactory`).
```

How can I use a custom config file for webpack properly and fix this error ?

Comment: You can watch working webpack configuration [here](https://github.com/vladilenm/rxjs-youtube-course/blob/final/webpack.config.js).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For using loaders of `webpack` you should add `rules` property with test regex indicating which files to transform.

```
 module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.(jsx|js)$/
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            use: {
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                options: {
                   presets: [ 'react', 'es2015' ]
                 } 
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

For more and precise information look at [documentation](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/loaders/#using-loaders) related to the version you have used.

Comment: Thanks I used the latest webpack docs to solve the problem